# How do I get Boot Camp back as default startup volume?

Tags: bootcamp, startup

I used to have Boot Camp as my default startup volume.

I have updated to 10.14.4 recently and since then Boot Camp is no longer shown under start volumes. My MacBook Pro boots to macOS now.

I can boot to Windows using the Alt key, but this is not what I want.

Is there any way to change it back to Boot Camp?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that it was not only an update of macOS, but I had also NTFS for Mac installed. This prevents the Boot Camp partition to be used as a startup volume. If you deactivate the NTFS driver in NTFS for Mac, it can be used as startup volume again.